# Jquery : Select a select option if it has a given text

Tags: jquery, performance

I have some predefined values that i get from

```
var str= $('#update-select').attr('data-type');  
var substr = vals.split(','); //gives  shipper, tester
substr.forEach(function(item) {
    // select the option from select box which has this string
    // make selected = selected
});
```

and i have a select

```
<select multiple="" id="update-select" data-type="shipper, tester">
    <option value="3">Shipper</option>
    <option value="4">Created by</option>
    <option value="5">test</option>
</select>
```

i have tried

```
$('#update-select option').filter(function () { 
    return $(this).html() == item; 
}).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

but is not working

Comment: so what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#update-select option[text=" + item+ "]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:contains` selector :

```
$('#update-select :contains(' + item + ')').prop('selected', true);
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/sTD9y/.